# Export to PNG script not running

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-window

I am new to running scripts in ArcMap and am trying to run simple code to export data driven pages to images. I am trying to run the script below, but when I hit enter nothing happens (no message, error or otherwise, images are not exported - I can't tell if anything is happening at all):

```
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
... for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
...   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\ParcelAtlas_Page" + str(pageNum) + ".png")
... del mxd
```

It's difficult to troubleshoot the code when I don't get any kind of output/feedback from the dialog. Having little to no experience running Python scripts I'm wondering if there is something simple I am missing or a setting I need to change, etc.

Comment: So `mxd` does exist, is data driven pages turned on and set up correctly in this map document?

Comment: Yes, data driven pages are turned on and set up correctly in the document (can export to PDF with data driven pages using the export dialog just fine)

Comment: I see you have copied the code from the help page [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/page-layouts/exporting-data-driven-pages.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AFD4C0FBDE6F4104B2BE9D52814867B9) in verbatim. It would be highly unlikely that your personal project is the same as some sample code found on the help page. So the next obvious question to check is does c:\temp exist on your computer? If so then you need to expand your question to show what you have set up.

Comment: Did you hit Enter twice at the end?

Comment: And consider using an error handler with your code.  Error handlers are easy to use and often return details about where and why your code is failing. If no error is returned and you have no error you can assume your code (or some portion of your code) is skipping some loop or function.  Here is a link to error handlers in Pro:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/error-handling-with-python.htm